# Microsoft Azure Cognitive Project Oxford Speech API Text to Voice jQuery REST example

Tags: jquery, rest, azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

Anybody got a working jQuery REST code example for Azure Project Oxford Speech API.

I have the Azure app service up and  Keys.  Just need a simple prototype page that on load plays some text currently in a specific

Possible to even do this with just with javascript/jQuery and REST on the client side and no server side code?

Also, I installed the server side sample, but it only plays from localhost. No errors, but will not play from an azure web site.

UPDATE: using client js code only.  I was able to authenticate and I'm getting RIFF AWAVEfmt  >}data back but can't seem to figure out how to play it from browser.  I get no errors.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: ttsServiceUri,
    beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/ssml+xml");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("X-Microsoft-OutputFormat", "riff-16khz-16bit-mono-pcm");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + response.access_token);
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "TTSNodeJS");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("X-Search-AppId", "xxxxxxxxxxxDAA29772419F436CA");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("X-Search-ClientID", "xxxxxxxxxxxx1A480F00935DC390960");

    },
    data: post_data,
    type: "POST"
})
```

.done(function (response) {
 [image]
      var audio = new Audio(response);
      audio.play();

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are looking at the text to speech part of the API? You basically want to play the audio of some text that you pass to the api using on JavaScript technologies? If I build a working sample, will you credit me with an answer?

Comment: sure, but will it be client only connecting to Azure Cognitive and work from IE, FF and Chrome?

Comment: absolutely give you credit.  Can it be done with html5 audio client? IE seems to need a file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be done - I'll need to look into it though and it will take me a few days. I'll update here if/when I have a working sample

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/api-reference-rest/home) you can find the API documentation.
For a working example have a look at this sample code using the Cognitive Services Speech API http://github.com/Danielius1012/Text-To-Speech
Useful code snippet from the code mentioned above:

```
function sendAudioRequest()
{
textToSpeak = $("#my-text")[0].value;
sendString = "<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='"+language+"'><voice xml:lang='"+language+"' xml:gender='Female' name='"+nameLanguage+"'>"+textToSpeak+"</voice></speak>";

console.info($("#text-to-speak"));

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
    {
        context.decodeAudioData(xhttp.response, function(buffer) 
        {
            speechBuffer = buffer;
            console.info(speechBuffer);
            playAudio(speechBuffer);  
        });

    }
}; 

xhttp.open("POST", audioURL, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/ssml+xml');
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + token);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Microsoft-OutputFormat", 'riff-16khz-16bit-mono-pcm');
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Search-AppId", '07D3234E49CE426DAA29772419F436CA');
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Search-ClientID", '1ECFAE91408841A480F00935DC390960');
xhttp.responseType = 'arraybuffer'

xhttp.send(sendString);
}
```